# Finding values in mongodb collection with multiple occurence

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongojs

I have a collection with documents as follows :

```
{id: 1, "year": "12", "type": "checking", "location": "nyc", "category" : "Admin"}
{id: 2, "year": "15", "type": "checking", "location": "ma", "category": "Normal"}
{id: 3, "year": "12", "type": "credit", "location": "nyc","category": "Admin"}
{id: 4, "year": 12, "type": "checking", "location": "nyc", "category" : "Admin"}
```

Now, i want to count the  'type' that appears more than once meeting the criteria location:nyc, year:12, category: Admin
So the desired result is
`{"Checking": 2}`

What way can I achieve the above?

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: I am aware of the aggregate function but don't know how to use finds with it. So do not have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $match and $group

```
db.collectionname.aggregate({$match: {location: 'nyc', year:'12', category:'Admin'}},
{$group: {_id:'$type', count:{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{count: {$gt:1}}}
)
```